# how to iterate over a list of list in jinja

Tags: jinja2

I have a list of list like :

```
    [[elem0, elem1, elem2], [elem3, elem4, elem5], [elem6, elem7, elem8], ...]
```

I wrote the follow template file :

```
    {% for result in results %}
        <tr>
            <td>result[0]</td>
            <td>result[1]</td>
            <td>result[2]</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

But it didn't work, What i can think is use nested for. Is there another method to access the element in the list in jinja?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You still need to output the loop variables inside braces.

```
{% for result in results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ result[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ result[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ result[2] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, consider a nested for loop:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <tr>
    {% for elem in result %}
        <td>{{elem}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can we use range or len on results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#filters) and built-in [filters.length](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.length) to get the length of a list and use the `range()` function.

```
{% for index in range(results | length) %}
    <tr>
    {% for element in results[index] %}
        <td>{{element}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```