# How to iterate through plain list in Jinja2 template and make an HTML table with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to iterate over a list in Jinja and display the table (borders) in HTML.

My list looks like this: mylist1 = [[e1, e2, e3, e4], [e5, e6, e7, e8], [e9, e10,..]]

The first element of the list [e1,e2,e3,e4] is headers.

I found the link to a similar answer: [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056622/how-to-iterate-over-a-list-of-list-in-jinja)

But its still not giving me the results in a table format.

```
<table>    
 {% for result in mylist1 %}
 <tr>
  {% for elem in result %}
    <td>{{elem}}</td>
    {% endfor %} 
  </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

I am getting the results in one line as - [e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,..].

What I want is to create a table with borders from this list. Could anyone please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What data is Flask sending?

Comment: It is sending a list. I am appending all the elements using .append() method

Comment: It is sending a list, but how heavily nested is it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But the list looks exactly the way I've mentioned above. I can print the exact list from my code if you want.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the view handler code that renders this template.